# pull out data from array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function that takes data from an input and saves it as data in an array during registration. Now I want another function to check during login if the data exists and if it matches. How can I do this using javascript only?
In short, I need a function that checks if the data entered by the user exists and if so, logs him in.

```
function saveData() {
  let name, email, password;
  name = document.getElementById("username").value;
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  let user_records = new Array();
  user_records = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    : [];
  if (
    user_records.some((v) => {
      return v.email == email;
    })
  ) {
    alert("Email wykorzystany");
  } else {
    user_records.push({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(user_records));
  }
}
```

I know that this is not how registration should be done. I am just doing it to learn new things.

Comment: I don't get, you are already comparing the 2 email to check if it is already saved, what do you want to do?

Comment: @Lafa In short, I need a function that checks if the data entered by the user exists and if so, logs him in.

Comment: `How can I do this using javascript only` I understand you are trying new things and hence wanted to call it out, anything with localstorage can be done in  only & only via JS. I do see few things wrong with your code but could you write down what exactly isn't working? Like what's the error message you seeing?

Comment: @InsaneSuperSand so you need a registration page, and a login page, like this you are only registering new users, right? PS: I tried your code and everything is working, I simply made some changes to make it more cleaner, but for the registration in the local storage it works

Comment: @Lafa  i do have login and register page.  Now I just don't know how to make the login work.

Comment: I'll try to drop you an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a basic login, when you verify that the  emmail and password are right, you can do wathever you want

```js
function checkData() {
        const name = document.getElementById('username').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        let user_records = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

        if (
          user_records.find((user) => {
            return user.name == name && user.password == password;
          })
        ) {
          alert('Logged in');
          // do your things here
        } else {
            alert('wrong email or password');
          // do your things here
        }
      }
```

```html
<input id="username" />
    <input id="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="checkData()" />
```

Extra:
This is a thing that you can do only for learning purpose, wich is to add a key to the local storage, for example: localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true) and set in every page a check for this value, if is true show the page, if is false redirect to login. In the real world we use JWT tokens that contains all the information about the user etc... You can search for JWT token authentication on google and learn that, wich is really usefull in the front-end world

Comment: It's working! Thanks! I have been struggling with this for a long time, and finally it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function saveAndTestUser() {
  // here use const as they are not updated
  const name = document.getElementById("username").value;
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  // Get all the records of the users
  // prefer camelcase : not a rule though but it's better this way
  const storedUsers = localStorage.getItem('users')

  // if there are no stored users then assign empty array 
  // so that we don't get unexpected errors
  const userRecords = storedUsers ? JSON.parse(storedUsers): []

  // Checking if email already exists
  if(userRecords.some(user => user.email === email)){
    alert("user already exists")
    return false; // stops the function execution
  }
  
  // If email doesn't exists then the code below will be executed
  // Similar to if-else
  // Add current record to existing records
  const newRecords = [...storedUsers, {name, email, password}] 

  // Set the new record to storage
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(newRecords));
 
}
```